# How to override the Spring Data Mongo version from Parent Project?

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb

In my project, we've Parent module which is none of in our control and has using `mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar` and `spring-data-mongodb-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar`. But somehow I want to use ***latest versions*** of both *mongodb-driver-core* and *spring-data-mongodb*. How to override this from Parent module ?

I already went through the link: https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot, but doesn't works for me.

I want to either override Spring Boot starter version or want to use somehow `mongodb-driver-3.8.2.jar` and `spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar`

I've pom.xml file something like below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example.ahr</groupId>
        <artifactId>ahr-rest-api-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ahr-data</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ahr-data</name>
    <description>ahr Data Service </description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <mongo.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</mongo.version>
    </properties>
 ............
 ..................
 .................
```

Answer (score 0):

We simply need to override the `spring-boot-dependencies` from the Parent module, so that `Spring Data Mongo starter` can pick up the latest versions of itself.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Here is the one more change we need to make -

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.boot.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
</properties>
```